# Updating a property in an array after querying with $ne

Tags: javascript, mongodb, increment, sql-update

A document in my collection `rooms` has the following structure:

```
{
    "_id": { "$oid": "4edaaa4a8d285b9311eb63ab" },

    "users": [
        {
            "userId": { "$oid": "4edaaa4a8d285b9311eb63a9" },
            "unreadMessages": 0
        },

        {
            "userId": { "$oid": "4edaaa4a8d285b9311eb63aa" },
            "unreadMessages": 0
        },
    ]
}
```

I'd like to increment `unreadMessages` of the second user (the one at index 1 in the array), if I know the `ObjectId` of the *first* user. Knowing the `_id` of the document is sufficient for selecting, but for updating I need to be able to reference to the other user, so I'm also selecting by `users`. I'm doing so with the following update call:

```
collections.rooms.update(
    {
        _id: ObjectId("4edaaa4a8d285b9311eb63ab"),

        users: {           // not first user
            $elemMatch: { $ne: { userId: ObjectId("4edaaa4a8d285b9311eb63a9") } }
        }
    },

    {
        // this should increment second user's unreadMessages,
        // but does so for unreadMessages of first user
        $inc: { "users.$.unreadMessages": 1 }
    }
);
```

It increments `unreadMessages` of the *first* user, not of the second user. I guess this is because `$ne` actually matches on the first user, and apparently that's what `users.$` is referring to.

How should I modify this call so that the second user's `unreadMessages` is incremented?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you're doing the right thing, except for a little syntax dyslexia around the [$ne](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Advanced+Queries#AdvancedQueries-%24ne) query constraint.

So where you have

```
users: {           // not first user
    $elemMatch: { $ne: { userId: ObjectId("4edaaa4a8d285b9311eb63a9") } }
}
```

instead you want

```
users: {           // not first user
    $elemMatch: { userId: { $ne: ObjectId("4edaaa4a8d285b9311eb63a9") } }
}
```

If I had a nickel for every time I've done the same kind of swap ... I'd have a lot of nickels.  :)

Actually, if you want to tighten things up, the $elemMatch is not really needed, since you're only constraining one property of the matched array element.  I think you can boil the whole query criteria down to:

```
{
    _id: ObjectId("4edaaa4a8d285b9311eb63ab"),
    users.userId: { $ne : ObjectId("4edaaa4a8d285b9311eb63a9") }
}
```

Comment: I had to swap indeed. Though, the `$elemMatch` seems necessary since it isn't updating without. Everything is working now, thanks!